# To use the same begin-for-syntax definition in different files

Tags: syntax, racket

I'm in a bigger code and I need to do it like:

**file_1.rkt :**

```lisp
#lang racket

(provide define-type types-ref)

(require syntax/parse/define)

(begin-for-syntax
  (define types (make-hasheq)))

(define-syntax-parser define-type
  [(_ id type)
   (hash-set! types (syntax->datum #'id) (syntax->datum #'type))
   #'(void)])

(define-syntax-parser types-ref
  [(_ id)
   (writeln (hash-ref types (syntax->datum #'id)))
   #'(void)])
```

**file_2.rkt :**

```lisp
#lang racket

(provide (all-defined-out))

(require "file_1.rkt")

(define-type Atom Symbol)

(types-ref Atom)
```

out:

```lisp
Symbol
```

**file_3.rkt :**

```lisp
#lang racket

(require "file_1.rkt" "file_2.rkt")

(types-ref Atom)
```

out:

```lisp
; hash-ref: no value found for key
;   key: 'Atom
; Context (plain; to see better errortrace context, re-run with C-u prefix):
;   /Applications/Racket v8.0/collects/syntax/parse/define.rkt:20:4
;   /Applications/Racket v8.0/collects/syntax/wrap-modbeg.rkt:46:4
;   /...
```

It seems that for each syntax expansion `types` is instantiated again.

I need to share the same `types` for different files. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to store the information in a hash table like that? A simpler way is to actually define `id` in `define-type`, so that you can properly `provide` it, and the other modules can properly `require` it.

It looks like you want `define-type` to occur at compile-time, so you can use `define-syntax` to create the binding, and use `syntax-local-value` to reference it.

```
#lang racket

(provide define-type types-ref)

(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-syntax-parser define-type
  [(_ id type)
   #'(define-syntax id (quote type))])

(define-syntax-parser types-ref
  [(_ id)
   (writeln (syntax-local-value #'id))
   #'(void)])
```